# How Do I Reset My Root Password on MySQL on a Mac?

Tags: macos, mysql

I'm using SequelPro (http://www.sequelpro.com/)
and I would like to know how to reset my root password.
I'm trying to log in as

> host: localhost
>   username: root
>   password: (BLANK)

But I keep getting this error:

> Unable to connect to host because access was denied.
>   Double-check your username and password and ensure that access from your current location is permitted.
>   MySQL said: `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Any suggestions?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you're using to run MySQL, you could take a look at [the official instructions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-unix).

If you're using [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) or something similar you need to find where `mysqladmin` is located.

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password ’somepassword’
```

If you are using another installation of mysql, you may be able to find out where it is located with:

```
$ which mysqladmin
```

Comment: Thanks! I was using the program MySQL.
I started using MAMP thanks to your suggestion, and now it all works. Thanks again!

Comment: Just an FWI you can accept this as the answer by clicking the check mark under the vote indicators. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the procedure to reset password of root user.

1) Stop mysql (Kill mysql process or run following command)

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
```

2) Start it in safe mode

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

3) Open another terminal and run the following command (Keep last terminal open)

```
mysql -u root
```

4) Run the following command with suitable new password on the mysql console

```
mysql > UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';
```

5) `mysql > FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

6) Quit from both terminals and open new terminal and connect to mysql with root user and new password

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

Comment: old post but still relevant - for step 3 on Mac OS Mojave run `sudo mysql -u root`